# How to copy workbook (.aspx file) from html link to current workbook

Tags: asp.net, vba

I have trouble with the following tasks in excel VBA:

At my work, we use a document management platform called TeamShare: [https://www.lector.dk/en/products/]

I want to create a code in VBA, that loops over a range of links to this document management platform in my workbook, ie. loops over other workbooks, opens them and then copies a specified sheet to my current workbook.

I have tried putting together bits of codes from other sites, and the code works just fine when i run it in break mode. However, when I run the code all at once, the Excel program reopens, such that the current workbook cannot "communicate" with the opened workbook and I end up in an infinity loop (so no direct error message).

This is the code that only works in break mode:

```
Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet Dim i As Long Dim Count As Long Dim WBCount As Long Dim LastRow As Long Dim wb As Workbook Dim ws As Worksheet Dim URL As String Dim IE As Object Dim doc As Object Dim objElement As Object Dim objCollection As Object

Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet

LastRow = wsCopyTo.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
```

The purpose of this piece of code is to get the DocID

```
A = InStr(wsCopyTo.Range("B" & i), "documentid=") + Len("documentid=")
B = InStrRev(wsCopyTo.Range("B" & i), "&")
DocID = Mid(wsCopyTo.Range("B" & i), A, B - A)

'Get URL
URL = wsCopyTo.Range("B" & i)
'Count number of open workbooks
WBCount = Workbooks.Count
With IE
```

New is the comman that opens excel sheet. This works as planned in breakmode, however the excel program reopens when i run the code all at once. I have tried other commandos here: "Workbooks.Open", I couldn't get this one to open the file and "Application.FollowHyperlink" only worked in break mode too, however, much much slower

```
.Navigate URL

'This was my solution to how to stop the rest of the code from executing until the new workbook has loaded. 
Do Until Workbooks.Count = WBCount + 1: Loop
End With

'Unload IE
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing
'So in order to activate the workbook from the URL, I am looping over all my open workbooks and matching them on their unique Document ID. I found that the workbook from the URL wasn´t the "active workbook" per default.

For Each book In Workbooks If Mid(book.Name, 12, Len(DocID)) = DocID Then

    book.Activate
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    End If
Next book
```

Here i copy the desired sheet to my initial workbook

```
wb.Worksheets("SpecificSheetIWantToCopy").Copy After:=wbCopyTo.Worksheets("Sheet1") wbCopyTo.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = DocID

Next i

End Sub
```

I am using excel 2010.

I hope you can help me resolve this problem. Please ask if you need any more information, that i haven´t provided.

Thanks in advance.